# How can I specify an array as a parameter

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following method:

```
public void testMethod() {
    String id = Card.people[4];
    id = Card.rooms[4];             
}
```

String id should either equal Card.people[4] or Card.rooms[4]. So how can I specify in the parameter what id should equal?

Comment: This part is confusing me: *So for example, if I called testMethod(people), then the String "id" would equal the fourth slot of people array...and if I wanted to do it the other way, I would just call testMethod(rooms)*

Comment: id should either equal Card.people[4] or Card.rooms[4]. So how can I specify in the parameter what id should equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the general format you could use:

```
public void testMethod(MyType[] array) {
    MyType fourthElement = array[4];
}
```